# PySide moving one window to the screen location of another window

Tags: pyside, maya

I would like to get the screen location of one window, and then take those coordinates and move another window to that location. Thanks.

Comment: Hello again! Is this window one of yours, or something from Maya?

Comment: Thank, it was my own window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the position, you can get the position of the first window:

```
    pos = self.first.pos().toTuple()
```

and move the second one there:

```
    self.second.move(*pos)
```

You can do the same with its size:

```
    size = self.first.size().toTuple()
    self.second.resize(*size)
```